# Ansible win_xml removing xml element fails

Tags: xml, ansible

I am running the following task in an ansible playbook after installing iis trying to remove the default website document files from applicationhost.config.

```
  - name: Remove defaultDocument Files From applicationhost.config
    win_xml:
      path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config
      xpath: /configuration/system.webServer/defaultDocument/files/*
      state: absent
```

The play fails with the following error:

```
The full traceback is:
The property 'removed' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:162 char:21
+ ...             $result.removed += $result.removed + $removedNode.get_Out ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

ScriptStackTrace:
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 162

fatal: [win2019-local-096]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: The property 'removed' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was an issue because I was running my playbook with debug -vvvv so that I could debug the output. As soon as I ran that without the verbosity it succeeded.

Comment: Your observation is correct. When enabling the debug using '-vvvv', its breaking the deployment but with out '-vvvv' its working well. I will open an ansible bug for this.